# Spring Auditable entity is being modified even when nothing has changed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, audit

NOTE: This is a complicated question so I hope I've covered the relevant parts. If not, I will edit and add more information as requested.

We're using Spring (4.1.0) with Hibernate (4.3.6) and we've defined a base class that all of our entities extend called `BaseAuditableEntity` (code below). When any entity is loaded in a @Transactional method and then modified and saved, that entity's `modified_by_user_id` and `modified_ts` are both updated with the id of the user logged in performing whatever change is being made.

Our problem is that whenever an `AppUser` (which also extends BaseAuditableEntity) is loaded in one of these `@Transactional` methods, it's also seeing the `modified_by_user_id` and the `modified_ts` being set even if it hasn't been modified. This creates a problem because we're writing to our user table with almost every request when we don't need to be. Note that this also may affect `@Transactional` methods that don't load the `AppUser` explicitly because the `AuditorBean` loads an `AppUser` itself.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact that the AppUser entity is part of the BaseAuditableEntity itself. Can someone confirm this? Is there a way to solve this problem?

Our `BaseAuditableEntity` class that every entity including AppUser extends:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseAuditableEntity implements Auditable<AppUser, Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hibernate_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "hibernate_sequence", sequenceName = "blah_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @CreatedBy
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by_user_id")
    private AppUser createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "modified_by_user_id")
    private AppUser lastModifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "created_ts")
    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "modified_ts")
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    // ...
}
```

Our `JpaConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "blah.blah.blah"})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {AuditorBean.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorBean")
public class JpaConfig extends BaseConfig {

    // ...

}
```

And our `AuditorBean`:

```
@Component
public class AuditorBean implements AuditorAware<AppUser> {

    @Override
    public AppUser getCurrentAuditor() {
        // omitting some code that finds a user. I think the only relevant thing here
        // is that we're using the repo to find the user by ID and not using an
        // entity that's already been loaded
        return userRepository.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to keep audit simple anddefine

```
@CreatedBy
private Long createdBy;
```

without actual association and store there just AppUser's id.

@Component
public class AuditorBean implements AuditorAware {

```
@Override
public Long getCurrentAuditor() {
    // .... find out the id
    return id;
}
```

}